# Accees to dynamically added HTML tages to ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net

I add dynamically html code in page load to section of page. like this:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //HTML file
    string file = Server.MapPath("~/ProductsF/DetailFiles/"+Request.QueryString["Page"]);        
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
    HtmlGenericControl hgc = new HtmlGenericControl();
    if (File.Exists(file))
    {
        //load html file
        StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(file);
        hgc.InnerHtml = sr.ReadToEnd();            
        sr.Close();
        sr.Dispose();
    }
    this.ContentPanel.Controls.Add(hgc);
}
```

but i want to access some html control in prerender event and change some attribute. but i can't to access those html controls.

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    MakeAllUrlFullyQualified(Page);
    base.OnPreRender(e);
}


private void MakeAllUrlFullyQualified(Control control)
{
    if (control.HasControls())
    {
        foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
            MakeAllUrlFullyQualified(child);
    }

    if (control is HtmlAnchor)
    {
        HtmlAnchor anchor = control as HtmlAnchor;
        anchor.HRef = WebHelper.GetFullyUri(ResolveUrl(anchor.HRef));
    }
    else if (control is HtmlImage)
    {
        HtmlImage image = control as HtmlImage;
        image.Src = WebHelper.GetFullyUri(ResolveUrl(image.Src));
    }
    else if (control is HtmlLink)
    {
        HtmlLink link = control as HtmlLink;
        link.Href = WebHelper.GetFullyUri(ResolveUrl(link.Href));
    }
}
```

what is wrong in this code?

Answer (score 1):

You are adding HTML to your page through the `HtmlGenericControl.InnerHTML` property. You are not adding controls to it.

The only control you are adding is the `HtmlGenericControl` (hgc), but you are not adding any others.

Look through the documentation on [User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx) and [Master Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx) to see how to properly template a website in ASP.NET

**Edit:**

To access the HTML you are adding, you can do the following:

```
if (control is HtmlGenericControl)
{
    HtmlGenericControl myGenericControl = control as HtmlGenericControl;
    string innerHtml = myGenericControl.InnerHtml;
}
```

What you can't do is convert the HTML to controls.

Comment: i want access to some html tags that dynamically added in page load